# Using an Image (JAVA)

Tags: java, user-interface, joptionpane

So, I am making a program that the player searches different areas and each area has their own objects to look through and the game ends when a player searches an object. I want to display an image showing where the player ends. I have the images and have not been able to figure out how to display this image. I have tried with JOptionPane, yet when I get to the code, there is no image but the text still shows. This is what I have to show the image. Why does this not show the image?

```
ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("Yard.jpg");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yard" , "The End" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, img1);
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example. This means you must provide code that we can copy and paste and compile ourselves. Note that this does **not** mean to just copy and paste all of your code here. You should only show us enough code to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Answer (score 0):

Uhm make sure path to the image is correctly there, something like this:

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/images/Yard.jpg"))
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation that the code will work for an image stored in resources/images folder, under project root folder. Also `getClass()` can not be used in static method.

Comment: I imported he images by dragging them into a project and it automatically put them into a place called <default package>, I can only put them in other folders. What would be the path to this? I am not good with paths. Sorry